# Помогите с flexbox'ом

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

Как придать элементу значение `justify-content: center` и `flex-start` одновременно? Получается что мне необходимо сделать все блоки в центре, а последнюю строчку сделать `flex-start` для того что бы последний элемент был не в центре, а прижат к левому краю. Но я не пойму как этого добиться.
[image: aa]
Вот что мне нужно, только это все в центре разместить... А не иметь ужасный отступ справа

Comment: Над этой проблемой бьются многие века

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для решения вашей задачи можно вообще без flex *justify-content* обойтись. Объедините всё ещё в один блок и просто установить `margin: 0 auto;`. В общем, вот:

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.block-flexbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 330px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block-flexbox-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-flexbox">
    <div class="block-flexbox-item"></div>
    <div class="block-flexbox-item"></div>
    <div class="block-flexbox-item"></div>
    <div class="block-flexbox-item"></div>
    <div class="block-flexbox-item"></div>
    <div class="block-flexbox-item"></div>
    <div class="block-flexbox-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: мне кажется, там вопрос иного рода, не может быть все так просто )))

Comment: @NeedHate, ну задачу показанную на картинке я выполнил :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{display:flex;justify-content:center}
.flx{border:2px solid green;height:50px;width:50px;margin:5px}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="flx"></div>
 <div class="flx"></div>
 <div class="flx"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="flx"></div>
 <div class="flx"></div>
 <div class="flx"></div>
</div>
```